# Proper translation for 本日の宿題は無個性な僕のこと

Tags: translation, song-lyrics

So these lyrics are from a song and the official translation I found was "Today's homework is about my basic self". I have a couple of problems with this namely that 無個性 is made up of 無 meaning nothing, and 個性 meaning individuality. So what I get from that is 無個性 should be translated as "Lack of personality". こと means "mater of" saying this is a matter of 僕の (my) personality or as I remake it "Matter of the lack of being myself". Using this, if I am correct shouldn't the translation be along the lines of "Today's homework is about the lack of being myself/ my individuality"? So to sum up is 1.) My translation correct and 2.) Did I make any mistakes in the above comments? 3.) What exactly does 「な」 mean as it is used in 本日の宿題は　無個性な僕のこと」

Comment: Smells like [ロストワンの号哭](http://vocaloid.wikia.com/wiki/%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%AF%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E5%8F%B7%E5%93%AD_(Lost_One_no_Goukoku)) [The Lost One's Weeping]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.) Is my translation correct?

Exactly!

> 2.) Did I make any mistakes in the above comments?

No.

> 3.) What exactly does 「な」 mean as it is used in 本日の宿題は　無個性な僕のこと」?

無個性 is a noun. 無個性な is a na-adjective.

豊富 (abundance) is a noun. 豊富な (abundant) is a na-adjective.

有名 (fame) is a noun. 有名な (famous) is a na-adjective.

Therefore, "na" is the na-adjective making particle.

Answer (score 3):

I think your interpretation of 無個性 is generally correct, as that is an adjective that means something along the lines of "someone who has a lack of individuality/personality" (see [this](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E7%84%A1%E5%80%8B%E6%80%A7%E3%81%AA)). The な is because this word is being treated as a "na-adjective", just like words such as 素敵 and 立派 can be.

However I think your translation, while close, is a little bit off. I believe the grammar implies something more like this:

> Today's homework is about me, who has a complete lack of individuality"

By the way, doing a google search with a portion of this translation, I found someone saying "me, who has no personality" [this](https://www.wattpad.com/story/71075717-personality) which is another good translation.